# Running a program (command) on terminal after login screen in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, terminal, login, startup

**NOTE :-** `This is not a duplicate question`. I have searched about 100 times on this site and several others including Ubuntuforums,askubuntu and stackoverflow. I couldn't get my work done.

**OBJECTIVE :-**  I want to have a command running on three different terminals which will all start with the login of the user. The 3 terminals will be opened simultaneously without any inter-relationship.

[image: Sensors-Command]

[image: Sensors-Monitoring]

[image: Open Processing]

How can I achieve this? I tried doing things which I have listed below :-

1. Added script for doing this at `system startup(using /etc/init.d and making symbolic links in rc2.d)` which started the services but didn't show the processes running in the terminals.
2. Took direct help of rc.local(inside rc.d) and appended the commands in that file as suggested somewhere. That also did the same as first.
3. Directly used the `autostart-program` options to start programs manually after login of the user. This too failed to open the terminal.

My Script content :-

```
#! /bin/bash
gnome-terminal -e "watch sensors";   ### this is working, others aren't.
gnome-terminal -e gedit /etc/hostname  ### not working
gnome-terminal -e processing /home/Desktop/samudra_gui/samudra_gui.pde
```

***QUESTION :- HOW SHOULD I ACHIEVE THIS ??? WHAT SHOULD I DO SO THAT THE 3 TERMINALS DON't AUTOCLOSE AFTER EXECUTING 3 COMMANDS AFTER LOGIN ? PLEASE HELP!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may try:

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'watch sensors'"
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'gedit /etc/hostname'"
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'processing /home/Desktop/samudra_gui/samudra_gui.pde'"
```

and start this script from `.bashrc` or write this in `.bashrc`

Comment: Gives error as `Failed to parse arguments: Unknown option -c
`!

Comment: ah ok try this: ```gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'watch sensors'"
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'gedit /etc/hostname'"
gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'processing /home/Desktop/samudra_gui/samudra_gui.pde'"```

Comment: Yeah, that helped. Thanks a lot... An upvote for you too...

Comment: Thanks :D you are the first one, I could help in this forum :D

Answer (score 1):

Edit `.bashrc` Or `.bash_profile`.
http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html

Comment: @shekharsuman yup yup. I had the same issue.